# How to embed a flash player in my Android app?

Tags: android, flash

How do I embed a flash player in my Android app?

Answer (score 0):

The Flash Player for Android has been [discontinued](http://www.itworld.com/289812/adobe-flash-discontinued-android-today-making-way-html5) for over a year.